# If $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{m = p}^n {{}^n{C_m}.{}^m{C_p}} } = 19$ , then the value of $n$

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

The question state that if $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{m = p}^n {{}^n{C_m}.{}^m{C_p}} }  = 19$ , then the value of $n$ is ____

I tried to do some steps mainly $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {{}^m{C_p}\sum\limits_{m = p}^n {{}^n{C_m}} }  = 19 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {{}^m{C_p}\left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^n {{}^n{C_m}}  - \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{p - 1} {{}^n{C_m}} } \right)}  = 19$

$ \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {{}^m{C_p}\left( {{2^n} - \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{p - 1} {{}^n{C_m}} } \right)}  = 19$ but not able to proceed.

I copied both question and picture with ease

Comment: If we put $n=3$ in $3^n-2^n$ we get 19, hence $n=3$

Comment: $19$ is very small...surely trial and error is the way to go here.

Comment: Please, avoid the use of images. Images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries. Type the question using MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

$\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n\sum\limits_{m =p }^n {m\choose p} {n\choose m} = \sum\limits_{p = 1}^n \sum\limits_{m =p }^n{\dfrac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}}\cdot {\dfrac{m!}{p! (m-p)!}}=\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n \sum\limits_{m =p }^n{\dfrac{n!}{(n-m)!}}\cdot {\dfrac{1}{p! (m-p)!}} $

> Now multiply and divide Expression with $(n-p)!$ so that can form ${n\choose p}={\dfrac{n!}{(n-p)!p!}}$, also ${\dfrac{(n-p)!}{(m-p)!(n-p)!}}={n-p\choose m-p}$

Hence above expreesion turn into $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n\sum\limits_{m = p}^n{n\choose p}{n-p \choose m-p}=\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {n\choose p}\sum\limits_{m = p}^n{n-p \choose m-p}$

Also Note that $\sum\limits_{m = p}^n{n-p \choose m-p}={n-p\choose 0}+{n-p\choose 1}+{n-p\choose 2}+....+{n-p\choose n-p} =2^{n-p}$

So Expression Turns into $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n {n\choose p} 2^{n-p}={n\choose1}2^{n-1}+{n\choose 2}2^{n-2}+.....+{n\choose n}2^{0}={(2+1)^n-2^n}$

Hence $\sum\limits_{p = 1}^n \sum\limits_{m = p}^n{m\choose p} {n\choose m}=3^n-2^n$

Hence $3^n-2^n=19\implies n=3$

Answer (score 1):

We have :
$$\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{m}=\frac{m!}{p!(m-p)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}=\frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}\cdot \frac{(n-p)!}{(n-m)!(m-p)!}=\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-p}{n-m}$$

Therfore :

$$\sum_{p = 1}^n {\sum_{m = p}^n }\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{m}=\sum_{p = 1}^n {\sum_{m = p}^n }\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-p}{n-m}=\sum_{p = 1}^n \left[ {\binom{n}{p} {\sum_{m = p}^n }\binom{n-p}{n-m}}\right]=\sum_{p = 1}^n\binom{n}{p}2^{n-p}=3^n-2^n$$

Therfore:
$$3^n-2^n=19 \implies n=3$$

Answer (score 1):

Combinatorial solution: we have $\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{m=p}^n\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{m}=A-B$ where

$$A=\sum_{p=\color{red}{0}}^n\sum_{m=p}^n\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{m}=3^ n$$

counts the number of ways to choose $X\subseteq Y \subseteq Z$ where $Z$ is a fixed set of $n$ elements, and

$$B = \sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}=2^n.$$

Indeed $A=3^n$ because each element in $Z$ can be in exactly one of three disjoint subsets $X$, $Y-X$, or $Z-Y$.

Solving $3^n-2^n=19$ gives $n=3$.